# $\|T_af-f\|_\infty\rightarrow 0,\ a\rightarrow 0\Rightarrow\ f$ has uniformly continuous representative

Tags: lebesgue-measure, uniform-continuity

Let $f\in L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d)$ (where the measure we're working with is the Lebesgue measure) and I have to prove the following equivalence :
$f$ has a uniformly continuous representative if and only if $\|T_af-f\|_\infty \rightarrow 0$ as $a\rightarrow 0$
where $T_af$ is defined almost everywhere by $T_af(x)=f(a+x)\ \forall a,x\in \mathbb{R}^d$.
I think I managed to prove the forward implication but I have no idea how to prove the inverse one. Here is my work :
Let $g$ be a uniformly continuous representative of $f$ and $\epsilon >0$. Let $\eta>0$ such that $|g(x)-g(y)|<\epsilon\ \forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}^d,\ \|x-y\|<\eta$.
Then $\forall a\in \mathbb{R}^d\ (\|a\|<\eta\Rightarrow |g(x+a)-g(x)|<\epsilon\ \forall x\in \mathbb{R}^d$).
So $\forall a\in \mathbb{R}^d$ such that $\|a\|<\eta$ we have:
$\|T_af-f\|_\infty=\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}^d}|g(x+a)-g(x)|<\epsilon$ and so $\|T_af-f\|_{\infty}\rightarrow 0$ as $a\rightarrow 0$.
I would be grateful for any help with the inverse implication or if you could check my answer for the forward implication.

Comment: To begin with, forget about the almost everywhere thing. Assume that $f$ is defined everywhere and that it satisfies $\|T_a f-f\|_\infty\to 0$ as $a\to 0$. This is exactly a reformulation of the uniform continuity property, you proved one implication, now try and prove the other one. Later, we'll see how to put the "almost everywhere" part in it.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro if $\epsilon >0$ and if $f$ is uniformly continuous then $\exists \eta>0$ such that $\forall x,y\ ||x-y||<\eta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon $ and so $\forall |a|<\eta$ we have $|f(x+a)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ which implies that $||T_af-f||_{\infty}\le \epsilon$.

Comment: Yes. This is one implication. For the other, unpack the definition of $\|T_a f - f\|_\infty\to 0$. You'll see that it is exactly the same things as the definition of uniform continuity.

Comment: If $\| T_af-f\|_{\infty}\rightarrow 0$ and $\epsilon>0$ then $\exists \eta>0$ such that $\forall |a|<\eta$ we have $\|T_af-f\|<\epsilon.$ So $\forall x,y$ such that $\|x-y\|<\eta$ we have $|f(x)-f(y)|=|T_{x-y}f(y)-f(y)|\le \|T_{x-y}f-f|_{\infty}<\epsilon$ and so $f$ is uniformly continuous. But now how do we deal with the "almost everywhere" part ?